# How to fix this CORS error?

Tags: errors, security, domain, http

I made a simple site on let's say `main_domain.com`.
Therefore I have `landing_page` CCT details page available on `main_domain.com/landing_pages/my-landing`.

My goal is **to hook one domain per `landing_page` CCT**, i.e

- domain1.com will serve `main_domain.com/landing_pages/my-landing`
- domain2.com will serve `main_domain.com/landing_pages/my-landing-2`
- ...

I added following lines in my .htaccess, making things work :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?landing_page=my-landing [NC,QSA]
```

Should I say that I added `domain1.com` as `ServerAlias` on vhost.
My problem now lies with CORS regarding fonts : `landing_page` page loads correctly except for embedded fonts for which I got error :

```
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://main_domain.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/dist/fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.otf' from origin 'http://domain1.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'main_domain.com'. Origin 'http://domain1.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried to

- Force `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in .htaccess, but it fails sometimes with error that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set multiple times.
- Add allowed origin using filter `allowed_http_origins`

  ```
   add_filter( 'allowed_http_origins', 'mytheme_add_origins' );

   function mytheme_add_origins($origin) {
      $origin[] = 'domain1.com';
      return $origin;
   }
  ```

  None of this worked. How can I make it work?

Stuck on this for a while, thanks !

Comment: When you got the message, the header was being sent twice?

Comment: Yes I saw it defined twice in response headers.

Comment: When you tried the second one, what headers were sent?

Comment: First Access-Control-Allow-Origin:domain1.com, second Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"